# Error on this Query (daily monthly sales)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.qty
     , s.price
     , s.date
     , p.name 
  FROM sales s 
  LEFT 
  JOIN products p 
    ON s.product_id = p.id
 ORDER 
    BY s.date DESC 
 LIMIT 5
```

```
function find_sale_by_dates($start_date,$end_date){   global $db;   
$start_date  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date));   
$end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date));   
$sql  = "
SELECT s.date
     , p.name
     , p.sale_price
     , p.buy_price
     , COUNT(s.product_id) total_records
     , SUM(s.qty) total_sales
     , SUM(p.sale_price * s.qty) total_saleing_price
     , SUM(p.buy_price * s.qty) total_buying_price
  FROM sales s
  LEFT 
  JOIN products p 
    ON s.product_id = p.id
 WHERE s.date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(s.date)
     , p.name
 ORDER
    BY DATE(s.date) DESC
 ";   return $db->query($sql);

 }
```

Comment: The point in the `ORDER BY` keyword in the query is a typo.

Comment: found the typo but still the same error thanks

Comment: Now add `$sql` variable value which is used in `return $db->query($sql);` operator.

Comment: sorry i dont get it where should i put it ?

Comment: Figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And also see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: "#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'newwdb.s.qty' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: You select date but group by date(date)

Comment: im using MySql right now should it be sql ?

Comment: You just shouldn't tag a different product, as experts on SQL Server aren't necessarily experts on MySQL.